# Issue with LIKE/OR operator in mysqli select statement in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm creating a simple mysqli prepared statement that selects records from a database based on a search. I want to search two different columns in my database table using the same search term that was submitted to find any matches in either the heading or the content details. I was following the Accessing Databases with Object-Oriented PHP with David Powers video on Lynda.com and adapting that tutorial to fit my needs. I have most of it working, however I'm running into an issue when I add a second variable in my sql statement. The issue is that it is not returning any rows. . Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, heading, details, layout FROM content WHERE ( details LIKE ? OR heading LIKE ? )";
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        $error = $stmt->error;
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $var1, $var2);
        $var1 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
        $var2 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
```

If I remove the part in the SQL after the first placeholder, and remove "$var2" from $stmt->bind_param('s', $var1, $var2); then the query works fine. For example, the following returns the correct results:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, heading, details, layout FROM content WHERE details LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        $error = $stmt->error;
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $var1);
        $var1 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
```

Once I add in the second variable, I get no results returned. I have also tried the following but that returns 0 results as well:

```
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $var1, $var1);
    $var1 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
```

I am brand new to prepared statements, so any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('s', $var1, $var2);` should be `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);` you've missed an `s`/argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not very familiar with parameter binding, shouldn't you be specifying a type for each argument, i.e.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
```

Comment: Indeed, OP is missing an argument.

Comment: Looks like that was it. I had that in there originally, but then kept removing stuff and re-arranging to see if I could locate the error, then must have just forgot to replace it and didn't catch it. Sometimes an extra pair of eyes is all it takes. Thanks!